# Как найти индексы одинаковых элементов в list<class>?

Tags: python, классы, list

Как найти индексы строк в которых **Город и Улица** одинаковые

```
class users: 
    def __init__(self, name, gorod, ulica): 
        self.name = name 
        self.gorod = gorod
        self.ulica = ulica
   
list = [] 

list.append( users('Иван', 'Москва', 'Ленина') )
list.append( users('Андрей', 'Москва', 'Ленина') )
list.append( users('Андрей', 'Москва', 'Маяковского') )
list.append( users('Артём', 'Ростов', 'Горького') )
list.append( users('Анна', 'Астрахань', 'Петрова') )
list.append( users('Артём', 'Астрахань', 'Петрова') )
```

На выходе должно получиться

```
list.append( users('Иван', 'Москва', 'Ленина_1') )
list.append( users('Андрей', 'Москва', 'Ленина_2') )
list.append( users('Андрей', 'Москва', 'Маяковского') )
list.append( users('Артём', 'Ростов', 'Горького') )
list.append( users('Анна', 'Астрахань', 'Петрова_1') )
list.append( users('Артём', 'Астрахань', 'Петрова_2') )
```

Comment: Не понятно. Вы хотите трансформировать исходный код программы? И вы пишете "найти индексы строк", а в ожидаемом результате, который приводите, нет никаких индексов.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Это написал не автор. Это было изменено strawdog. Я это увидел только после публикации ответа.

Comment: @farkon00 вы ошибаетесь: это была правка автора вопроса. Смотрите историю изменений https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1319936/revisions

Comment: @RomanKonoval Извиняюсь, перепутал правки. Я просматривал правки и случайно перепутал.

Comment: Иван, вам помог мой ответ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    k = 2
    is_added = False
    for j in range(i, len(list)):
        if i != j and list[i].gorod == list[j].gorod and list[i].ulica == list[j].ulica:
            if not is_added:
                list[i].ulica = list[i].ulica + '_1'
                is_added = True
            list[j].ulica = list[j].ulica + f'_{str(k)}'
            k+=1
```

Результат(Это вывод через for и  **str**, сам массив продолжает состоять из объектов, только изменённых) :

```
Name:Иван, Gorod:Москва, Ulica:Ленина_1
Name:Андрей, Gorod:Москва, Ulica:Ленина_2
Name:Андрей, Gorod:Москва, Ulica:Маяковского
Name:Артём, Gorod:Ростов, Ulica:Горького
Name:Анна, Gorod:Астрахань, Ulica:Петрова_1
Name:Артём, Gorod:Астрахань, Ulica:Петрова_2
```

Немного не оптимизировано, но работает. Если список не будет прям огромный, то всё ок.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил немного другое решение, при условии что я вообще верно понял суть задачи , что можно редактировать исходный класс 'users'  и добавлять свои классы.

Примерно так :

```
# имя класса пишется в камелкейс (UsersList, OrderedDict)
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, gorod, ulica):
        self.name = name
        self.gorod = gorod
        self.ulica = ulica

    @property
    def address(self):
        return (self.gorod, self.ulica)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name:<15} {self.gorod:<15} {self.ulica:<15}"


# создадим свой класс, отнаследованный от list
class UsersList(list): 
    def append(self, obj: User):
        """
        Переопределим стандартный метод класса list, так что бы при 
 добавлении очередного пользователя проверялся есть ли уже такой адрес и если есть то вносились необходимые изменения в адрес
        """
        if not isinstance(obj, User):
            print(f"UserList can append User class only, not {type(obj)}")

        if count := self.count_address(obj):
            if count == 1:
                o = self.get_by_address(obj.address)
                o.ulica = f"{obj.ulica}_{count}"
            obj.ulica = f"{obj.ulica}_{count+1}"
        super().append(obj)
    def count_address(self, obj:User):
        index = 0
        for o in self:
            if obj.address[0]==o.address[0] and obj.address[1] in o.address[1]:
                index += 1
        return index                                                                                                      

    def get_by_address(self, address:tuple) -> User:
        for o in self:
            if address[0]==o.address[0] and address[1] in o.address[1]:
                return o
                
# не стоит давать имя переменным, которое уже занять встроенными объектами (типа list, dict, etc)
ls = UsersList()

ls.append( User('Иван', 'Москва', 'Ленина') )
ls.append( User('Андрей', 'Москва', 'Ленина') )
ls.append( User('Андрей', 'Москва', 'Маяковского') )
ls.append( User('Артём', 'Ростов', 'Горького') )
ls.append( User('Анна', 'Астрахань', 'Петрова') )
ls.append( User('Артём', 'Астрахань', 'Петрова') )

for user in ls:
    print(user)
```

Если необходимо, можно так же переопределить метод extend. А так задачу считаю решенной. Вывод в консоль следующий:

```
Иван            Москва          Ленина_1       
Андрей          Москва          Ленина_2       
Андрей          Москва          Маяковского    
Артём           Ростов          Горького       
Анна            Астрахань       Петрова_1      
Артём           Астрахань       Петрова_2
```